# Segmentation Fault - Struct Inside Shared Memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In my program, I am using two structs inside my shared memory. I am initializing the first struct without any problem, but the initialization of the second struct keeps returning me segmentation fault. I have tried many ways to solve it but probably I am missing something...

```
typedef struct Struct1{
    int a;
    float b;
} Struct1;

typedef struct Struct2{
    int a;
} Struct2;

typedef struct{
    int c;
    Struct1* str1;
    Struct2* str2;
}Sh_Memory;

void main(){
    int shmid;
    Sh_Memory *shmem;
    //finding total_a and total_b...

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Sh_Memory) + total_a*sizeof(Struct1) + total_b*sizeof(Struct2), 0666);

    shmem = (Sh_Memory *)shmat(shmid,0,0);

    Struct1* struct1 = (Struct1*)((void*)shmem+sizeof(Sh_Memory));
    // ...
    //initialising struct1 with no problem

    Struct2* struct2 = (Struct2*)((void*)(shmem->struct1)+total_b*sizeof(Struct2));
        //wanting to initialize struct2
        (shmem->struct2).a = 0; //SEGFAULT

}
```

Any help?

EDIT: My shared memory has two different struct.
My main question is how to initialize correctly these to after accessing the shared memory.

Comment: The code that calculates `total_a`, `total_b` and `total_types` is missing

Comment: I don't get this code. `shmem+sizeof(Sh_Memory)` is different from `&shmem->struct1` as there is padding within the struct. Why don't you just `struct1 = &shmem->struct1` and `struct2 = &shmem->struct2`? Did you took care of unaligned access? The SEFAULT looks like unaligned access to variable. What is the value of total_types? How and why do you do additions of `void*` pointers and what does it mean? Can you provide a complete MCVE?

Comment: @mnistic this part of the code works fine

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought it had something to do with the offset.

Comment: I don't get this. You say that you get a SEGFAULT which would mean that you have compiled and executed the program, right? But the posted code can't compile! I has a number of errors. Did you post the correct code?

Comment: This gives an error `shmem->struct1` and so do this `shmem->struct2`. Further you should enable all compiler warnings. Then you will get some warnings that will explain where you are doing wrong. Example: " warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic"

Comment: @4386427 this code is a sample, obviously, I am making my mistake somewhere in the struct2 initialization.

Comment: @NickStavr You need to post the **real** code. This code can't compile! Example: `(shmem->struct2).a = 0;` gives "error: ‘shmem->str2’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?" You can't get help when you don't post the real code.

Comment: testing of the returns from system calls would also be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You might have messed up the typedefs and the naming of some variables.
I made a working example that I hope you can use for reference.
I had to fill in some unknowns tell me if the intention of the code was different than this.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} Struct1;

typedef struct {
    int a;
} Struct2;

typedef struct{
    int c;
    Struct1 *str1;
    Struct2 *str2;
} Sh_Memory;

int main(void)
{
    int shmid;
    Sh_Memory *shmem;
    int total_a = 3;
    int total_b = 3;

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Sh_Memory) + total_a * sizeof(Struct1) + total_b * sizeof(Struct2), 0666);

    shmem = (Sh_Memory *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

    shmem->str1 = (Struct1 *)((void *)shmem + sizeof(Sh_Memory));
    /* Init str1 */
    shmem->str1[0].a = 0;
    shmem->str1[0].b = 0.0;
    shmem->str1[1].a = 1;
    shmem->str1[1].b = 1.1;
    shmem->str1[2].a = 2;
    shmem->str1[2].b = 2.2;

    shmem->str2 = (Struct2 *)((void *)(shmem->str1) + total_a * sizeof(Struct1));
    /* Init str2 */
    shmem->str2[0].a = 0;
    shmem->str2[1].a = 1;
    shmem->str2[2].a = 2;

    /* Print str1 */
    for (int i = 0; i < total_a; i++) {
        printf("str1[%d] - a: %d, b: %f\n", i, shmem->str1[i].a, shmem->str1[i].b);
    }

    /* Print str2 */
    for (int i = 0; i < total_a; i++) {
        printf("str2[%d] - a: %d\n", i, shmem->str2[i].a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
str1[0] - a: 0, b: 0.000000
str1[1] - a: 1, b: 1.100000
str1[2] - a: 2, b: 2.200000
str2[0] - a: 0
str2[1] - a: 1
str2[2] - a: 2
```